# Why is my PHP source code showing?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

So, I added the following to my http.conf file:

```
Listen443

NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /PATH_TO/www
    ServerName www.domain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /PATH_TO/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /PATH_TO/domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /PATH_TO/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

https://www.domain.com works now, but it displays the PHP source code? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What is your Apache version, what platform are you running on and are you running PHP as a module or CGI?

Comment: Module, but I already got it working thanks to pst. But thanks for your help anyways, Dave!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Server configuration error" *is* the reason ;-)

It is choosing to serve PHP files as "plain content" instead of handing them to a PHP engine for processing. This doesn't have anything to do with SSL (it will just as happily send the "plain content" over a secure connection).

From [PHP: Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.processing):

```
AddModule mod_php.c
LoadModule php_module         modules/mod_php.so
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

And from [PHP pages won't load](http://forums.devarticles.com/web-server-configuration-51/php-pages-won-t-load-show-source-code-apache-2t-52648.html):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

See a pattern? :-) In any case, read the fine installation instructions for *the particular platform/server*.

Happy coding.

Comment: That worked thanks! :) I just tried to install SSL, and I never saw anyone mention to add these lines.

Comment: I just had to install libapache2-mod-php on an Ubuntu based Linux liked explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142172/apache-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing#comment65841862_12142315

Answer (score 5):

It could also be that your php.ini configuration is set to not parse code between short php tags.

Comment: AWESOME!!  Thank you!!  Ran into this problem when I ported my site to a local server.  I never even realized I accidentally used the shorttags in one of my files!

Answer (score 0):

In centos this can happen because of php-module missing, to fix that issue we have to install

> sudo yum install php-mysql php-devel php-gd php-pecl-memcache
>   php-pspell php-snmp php-xmlrpc php-xml

Answer (score 0):

Just type LOCALHOST in your browser. then it will open the http://localhost/htdocs/ location. then navigate to your php file. It will open accordingly.