# JQuery Ajax returns Source code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using JQuery Ajax on my website. I've tested it on our test server it worked perfectly, but when I tried to put it on our productive server the Ajax just returns the source code of the website itself.

JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sshin').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val();
        console.log(query);
        if (query != '') {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                success: function (data) {

                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'article', function () {
        var text = $('#sshin').val();
        text = text.substring(0, text.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
        text += $(this).text();

        var uniq = text.match(/\b\w+\b/g).filter(function (el, idx, a) {
            return idx === a.lastIndexOf(el);
        });

        text = uniq.join(',');

        $('#sshin').val(text);
        $('#sshout').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

PHP File:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["query"])){
     $query = $_POST["query"];
     return '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>';
  }
?>
```

Any idea why it returns something different than it should?

Comment: What do you mean by "source code of the website itself"? Can you post an example bit?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `ajax`. see the implementation of `search.php`

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264014/why-is-my-php-source-code-showing

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's litterally the html code from the file

Comment: Is it any possibility that you forget to use a parser of your PHP files?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja it works fine on our test server but i didnt change a single bit of the code..

Comment: Can you post the `search.php` and actual response you are getting now?

Comment: Maybe you receive error and see HTML output instead of PHP output?

Comment: Do you have to enable html file extension parsing with Apache?   You may want to compare settings between your environments.

Comment: @MisterPositive no difference between, already checked that.. could it be some way of redirect or something?

Comment: What is "the html code from the file"? You still haven't been precise. Is this the PHP code you mean, including the `<?php` tags? Or is it the HTML from whatever other page included the javascript?

Comment: @moopet just HTML, the html code the website is displaying including the Javascript, my css, etc.....

Comment: From what I can tell the server is configured to return soft 404 (returns the home page when a page is not found with 200 OK). In this case the ajax receives the whole HTML of redirected page.

Comment: @Rishabh that's actually something to work with, but still how is it possible that when i change the url to something wrong, that it returns a normal 404?

Answer (score 0):

This method once worked for me, hope it might help. Let me know.

```
 this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        return $this->output->set_output(json_encode('<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>'));
```

Comment: @Damon just remove the `return '<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>';` of your code. and then paste this and check what console.log(data) shows.

Comment: removed `this` and it works, but still returns the source code..
maybe it helps i found this: `https://myserver.ch/search.php?query=test,etc`
when you go into inspect in chrome and then on network..